# transposing multiple matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

So I have a question which says the following

> (a) Given $A=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>   3 & 0 \\
>  -1 & 2 \\
>   1 & 1
> \end{bmatrix}
> $, $B=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>   4 &-1 \\
>   0 & 2 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $, $C=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>   1 & 4 & 2 \\
>   3 & 1 & 5 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $. Compute $(BA^T-2C)^T$.

If I use Transpose properties, I get $(B^TA-2C^T)$

But if I transpose $B$, the rows of $B$ and the columns of $A$ don't agree so I can't do the matrix multiplication so I can't compute the matrix. Did I do the matrix properties properly? Or is there a mistake in the question?

Comment: In general $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$, not $A^TB^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $(A.B)^{T} = B^{T}.A^{T}$.   Now$(B . A^{T} - 2C)^{T} = (B . A^{T})^{T} - 2C^{T} = A.B^{T} - 2C^{T}$.

As you can see that matrix dimension of $A $ is $3$ by $2$ , $B^{T} $ is $2$ by $2 $ so  dimension of $A.B^{T} $ is $3$ by $2$ and $C^{T}$ is of size $3$ by $2$,thus we can subtract .